# не удаляется архив, после архивации

Tags: c++, winapi

[image: ошибка удаления]

в программе в определенное время запускается `cmd.exe` с помощью `ShellExecute`. и параметры для `cmd.exe` служат `Rar.exe -a [куда сохранить].rar [что сохранить]\`. вроде так. и я как понимаю что упаковка давным давно прошла. `cmd` вызывался с опцией `SW_HIDE`. может быть этот `cmd.exe` остался в памяти работать. но по ошибке такое впечатление, будто архив `Rar.exe` еще упаковывает каталог и поэтому нельзя удалить. Что делать?

Comment: Может быть ваше приложение, которое создало эти архивы не выгрузилось и не даёт их удалить? У меня было нечто похожее, я не мог удалить exe файл моей программы, помогла только перезагрузка. Попробуйте снять задачу "Command line RAR" и удалить архив. Потом запустите программу снова, но вез опции SW_HIDE, и посмотрите отчёт от выполнении операции

Comment: @Стас я думаю что вы не могли удалить exe файл программы, потому что эта программа была запущена и процесс был зависим от файла. хорошо я посмотрю. но по идее он с SW_SHOW делает всё нормально, но потом `cmd.exe` остается открытым. может в команду надо добавить еще типа такого `; exit`.

Comment: зачем вообще запускать cmd.exe вместо запуска rar напрямую?

Comment: @user7860670 а как? я просто в windows разработке не шарю. что-то получилось сделать.

Comment: Ну вместо cmd.exe указывать rar.exe, а потом параметры для него

Comment: @user7860670 о, и это сработает? даже если он находится в каталоге с программой?

Comment: Если находится в папке с проектом - должно сработать, но не факт, что Rar.exe запустится, находясь в папке с проектом. Возможно для него нужны зависимости, находящееся в папке, где он установлен. Если он запустится в ручную в папке проекта - используйте, если нет добавьте необходимые файлы (если программа не запустится Windows должен дать информацию из за чего это произошло)

Comment: хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

для запуска из любого места винрара:
"c:\program files\winrar\rar.exe" a C:\Documents\documents.rar C:\Documents
может быть х86 версия, в соответствующей папке програм файлс

https://winrar-fansite.com/instructions/konsolnye-komandy-winrar-primery.html

на скриншоте показано, что именно архиватор держит файл.
следовательно снять задачу с архиватора в диспетчере задач, при нажатии кнтрл+альт+дел. после этого удалить архив, если именно этот ответ искался...

если же нужно понять как в программе сделать так, чтобы архиватор не зависал (тэг c++ и winapi) - не могу помочь...

проверить ограничения версии (х86 или х64), имена файлов на кодировку и длину полного пути файлов - должно быть менее 256 символов от буквы диска до конца расширения самого глубокого и длинно именованного файла...